# javascript how to pass a window object to a function

Tags: javascript, html

My function, Slider, takes a window object, but it does not contain the body. And my code only works in mobile screen view.
In my function, while debugging below code,

console.log(windows.document);

if (!mySlider) {console.log(windows.document.body);}

The first console log shows that the body contains information; however, the second one shows that the body is null.
I am guessing this is relate

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    "use strict";
    /*
     *   Created by Waltor on 20181018.
     */
    var Slider = (function(windows) {
      var mySlider;
      var point = {
        start: 0,
        end: 0
      };

      function Slider(targetId, widthOfDisplayBlock, ImageSize, imageSrcArrays) {
        mySlider = document.getElementById(targetId);
        console.log(windows.document);
        if (!mySlider) {
          console.log(windows.document.body);
          console.log("mySlider >> " + mySlider);
          return;
        }
        createContainer(widthOfDisplayBlock, imageSrcArrays, ImageSize);
        createPhoneEvents(ontouchmove_, ontouchstart_);
      }

      function createContainer(widthOfDisplayBlock, imageSrcArrays, ImageSize) {
        var result = mySlider;
        var ImageSizeNumber = ImageSize.match(/\d/g).join("");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var dash = document.createElement("div");
        var dashWidth;
        var preSpace;

        result.style.overflow = "hidden";
        result.style.width = widthOfDisplayBlock;
        dashWidth = ((result.offsetWidth) - (ImageSizeNumber * 2)) / 2;

        ImageSize = ImageSize ? ImageSize : "100px";
        div.style = "width:" + ((imageSrcArrays.length + 1) * (ImageSizeNumber * 1 + dashWidth)) + "px;";
        dash.style = "float:left;position:relative;width:" + (ImageSizeNumber / 2) + "px;height:10px;top:" + (ImageSizeNumber / 2) + "px;";
        div.appendChild(dash);
        preSpace = dash.cloneNode(true);
        preSpace.style.width = dashWidth + "px";
        preSpace.style.background = "#ccc";
        div.appendChild(preSpace);

        for (var i = 0; i < imageSrcArrays.length; i++) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = imageSrcArrays[i];
          img.style = "float:left;width:" + ImageSize + ";height:" + ImageSize + ";";
          div.appendChild(img);
          div.appendChild(preSpace.cloneNode(true));
        }
        div.appendChild(dash.cloneNode(true));

        result.appendChild(div);
        return result;
      }

      function createPhoneEvents(ontouchmove, ontouchstart) {
        var result = mySlider;

        result.ontouchmove = ontouchmove;
        result.ontouchstart = ontouchstart;
        result.ontouchend = touchend;
      }

      function touchend() {
        point.start = 0;
        point.end = 0;
        console.log('clear!');
      }

      var count = 0;

      function ontouchmove_(event) {
        return touchmove(event, caculation);

        function caculation(start, end) {
          if (start && end) return end - start;
          return 0;
        }

        function touchmove(event, caculation) {
          console.log(count + " > " + event.touches[0].clientX);
          count++;
          var move = 0;
          var result = mySlider;
          var limit = {
            left: result.offsetLeft,
            right: result.offsetLeft + result.offsetWidth
          };

          point.end = event.touches[0].clientX;
          if (point && (point.end > limit.left) && (point.end < limit.right)) move = caculation(point.start, point.end);
          mySlider.scrollLeft -= move * 2;
          point.start = point.end;

          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
            "point.start >> " + point.start +
            "<br/>point.end >> " + point.end +
            "<br/>move >> " + move;
        }
      }

      function ontouchstart_(event) {

      }

      return Slider;
    })(window);

    var src = [
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg",
      "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg"
    ];

    function loading() {
      console.log(this);
      Slider("targetId", "60vw", "150px", src);
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', loading);
    window.addEventListener('load', Slider("targetId", "60vw", "150px", src));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <hr/>
  <div id="targetId" style="margin:0 auto;"></div>
  <hr/>
  <div id="test" style="font-szie:30px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

ed to how javascript loads information.
    Can anyone help me understand what is going on in my code
    and how to pass the window object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the window object is global. Any function in your code has access to it as long as you are running this code in a browser.

Next, your error is where you call your code:
You have

```
 <script>
   window.addEventListener('load', loading);
   window.addEventListener('load', Slider("targetId", "60vw", "150px", src));
 </script>
```

When it should be:

```
 <script>
   window.addEventListener('load', loading);
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       Slider("targetId", "60vw", "150px", src);
   })
 </script>
```

This is because your 'function' Slider is really a constructor via closure.
At the top you have var Slider = (function () { ... })(window)
so Slider is called automatically on its  own. After it gets called it actaully returnns  a function that you have defined inside of the closure called Slider.
This function returns null or undefined. So when you add the event listener, instead of givinng it a funnction to call when the window finishes loading, you are giving it a value.

Comment: Could you tell more detail about if I want it to be a library and let user directly to call it without that addEventListener and still need passing arguments?

Comment: Let's say in another hand, if I directly  execute the slider function, like "var x = Slider("targetId", "60vw", "150px", src);", and if this code is put before the <body>, and it's not working, but if it's after the <body> then it's working.
And I want to solve this kind of question, so I try to use "onload" method to delay loading and make it load after the <body> had loaded.

Comment: Well if you want this to be a library such that others can use it, you wouldn't need to change much. You already have your class which has a bunch of different methods. All you need to do is document how its meant to be used, and your users will use it that way. The way that you're doing it is fine. You want to wait for the page to load, and then execute your script. Almost all clientside javascript libraries begin after the page has loaded. Also it doesn't matter where you put the code, as long as it doesnt run anything until the page has loaded